# Polar Area onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I have following polar Area chart

[image]

bellow is the code

```
 var dataset = {
datasets: [{
    data: [Above30total, D21toD30total, D11toD20total,D0toD10total],
    backgroundColor: [
        "rgba(247, 13, 26,0.6)",
        "rgba(255, 128, 64,0.6)",
        "rgba(65, 163, 23,0.6)",
        "rgba(52, 45, 126,0.6)"
    ],
    label: 'My dataset' // for legend
}],
labels: ["ABOVE 30","21 - 30","11 - 20","0 - 10"]
};

var ctx = $("#myChart");
 new Chart(ctx, {
 data: dataset,
 type: 'polarArea' 
   }
 });
```

what I want is when I click on data shown are for example purple or if I click on green I want to get the data of that clicked area.

for example, if I click on purple I want to get the count of purple.

I have used below code but it is click method for the entire graph not for the data area.

```
$("#myChart").click(function (evt) {

   console.log(evt);
});
```

any idea how to archive this

Answer (score 0):

after mush research i found the answer

```
var ctx = $("#myChart");
 new Chart(ctx, {
 data: dataset,
 type: 'polarArea',
  options: {      
      'onClick' : function (evt, data) {


                }
            }
   }
});
```